# How can I put a hover on this Button Style?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

These are my codes for the Button. Somehow, background color only works if I do declare the style in the Button itself. Stating the background color in the const useStyles does not work, hence, I only did this. How can I code this where the background color changes when it hover on it?

```
<Button
      variant="contained"
      {...otherProps}
      className={classes.margin}
      style={{ backgroundColor: " #e31837" }}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
```

Comment: Which UI Library are you using?

Comment: @reachtokish I'm using material-ui for my react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the root property to change your button style ([docs](https://material-ui.com/pt/api/button/#css)), and also change its background on hover:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
  }
}));


<Button
      variant="contained"
      {...otherProps}
      className={classes.root}
      style={{ backgroundColor: " #e31837" }}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the styles:

```js
'&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: ‘red’
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
      variant="contained"
      {...otherProps}
      className={classes.margin}
      onMouseOver={this.toggleHover} 
      onMouseOut={this.toggleHover} 
      style={btnStyle}
    >
      {children}
</Button>
```

Then add a toggleHover function

```
toggleHover(){
    this.setState({hover: !this.state.hover})
}
```

Finally on your render function set your style as a variable

```
let btnStyle = {'backgroundColor: #e31837'};
if (this.state.hover) {
    btnStyle = {'backgroundColor: #000000'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following code snippet

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, withStyles, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { green, purple } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const ColorButton = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
    backgroundColor: purple[500],
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: purple[700],
    },
  },
}))(Button);

export default function CustomizedButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <ColorButton variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.margin}>
        Custom CSS
      </ColorButton>
    </div>
  )
}
```